# Kivy Program unable to run due to "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'properties'"

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to render a screen in Kivy and Python, with some basic text like so:

```
welcome_screen = Builder.load_string(
    '''
<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            text: 'Touch anywhere to proceed.'
            font_size: 24
    '''
    )

class WelcomeScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return welcome_screen

WelcomeScreen().run()
```

but the program is erroring out with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "/home/pi/Terminal2/main.py", line 143, in <module>
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 371, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 402, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 511, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 644, in parse_level
     current_object.properties[name] = rule
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'properties'
```

What is this error trying to tell me? I am trying to run the Python Script file containing the above code, on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Run `import pdb; pdb.settrace()` to obtain name and rule values where your builder has parsing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put <> in kv it is to specify a class to create a custom widget in that case there is no root widget in your kv

you could use that

```
welcome_screen = Builder.load_string(
    '''
Screen:
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            text: 'Touch anywhere to proceed.'
            font_size: 24
    '''
    )

class WelcomeScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return welcome_screen

WelcomeScreen().run()
```

Or if you want to create the class

```
class myScreen(Screen):
    pass
welcome_screen = Builder.load_string(
    '''
<myScreen>: #create widget myScreen
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            text: 'Touch anywhere to proceed.'
            font_size: 24
myScreen: #set widget myScreen as root
    '''
    )

class WelcomeScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return welcome_screen

WelcomeScreen().run()
```

If you don’t want to create the class in python you can also do

```
welcome_screen = Builder.load_string(
    '''
<myScreen@Screen>: #create widget myScreen from base class Screen
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome!'
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            text: 'Touch anywhere to proceed.'
            font_size: 24
myScreen: #set widget myScreen as root
    '''
    )

class WelcomeScreen(App):

    def build(self):
        return welcome_screen

WelcomeScreen().run()
```

You should also take a look at the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) because I think you have to use an ScreenManager

Comment: Thank you, did some reading last night and was able to figure out my shortcomings.